# Unbound prefix error in xarco file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting an unbound prefix error when I try to use an xarco macro. I do have the xmlns:xarco defined however. This is my xarco file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="[link to xarco wiki]" name="flexible">
  <xacro:macro name="test_macro" >
    <test name="x"/>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xarco:test_macro/>
</robot>
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Expat parsing error.  Check that:
 - Your XML is correctly formed
 - You have the xacro xmlns declaration: xmlns:xacro="[link to xarco wiki]"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/share/xacro/xacro.py", line 60, in <module>
    xacro.main()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 571, in main
    doc = parse(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1920, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 928, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unbound prefix: line 7, column 6
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74002/unbound-prefix-error-in-xarco-file/) by [munnveed](https://answers.ros.org/users/6052/munnveed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2013-08-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a typo in the xml in the OP: `<xarco:test_macro/>` while it should be `<xacro:test_macro/>`. That could be the cause of the error.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-06-27**:
This is it. Now I feel like I'm a dunderhead here...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-27**:
Typos are always the hardest to spot.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-08-30**:
This is the top Google result, so I'll add: I just had an xacro file give this error because the opening line was `<robot name="foo">` instead of `<robot xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="foo">`. Take note.